# Update row to be a criteria-based sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
NAME            ID            CREDIT
Item_A          10001         15600.00
Item_B          10002         16022.50
Item_C          10003         1800.00
Itens_ABC       10004         0.00
Machine_A       30001         5000.85
Machine_B       30002         3500.99
Machines_AB     30003         0.00
```

I want to update this table so it ends like this:

```
NAME            ID            CREDIT
Item_A          10001         15600.00
Item_B          10002         16022.50
Item_C          10003         1800.00
Itens_ABC       10004         33422.50
Machine_A       30001         5000.85
Machine_B       30002         3500.99
Machines_AB     30003         8501.84
```

I've tried this line in the VBA code in access for the Itens_ABC row:

```
SQL1 = "UPDATE INTO table SET CREDIT = IIF(ID = '10004', SUM(IIF(ID = '10003' OR ID = '10002' OR ID = '10001', CREDIT,0)), CREDIT);"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL1
```

But it displayed syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access is a pain when it comes to updates which use the same table as source in this fashion.

One option would be to do something using a temp table.

```
SQL1 = "Select sum(T.Credit) as Cr into tblTemp from test as T where T.ID in ('10001','10002','10003')"
docmd.runsql SQL1
SQL1 = "Update tblTemp,test set Credit=Cr where T.ID='10004'"
dcmd.runsql SQL1
```

Then just drop the temp table

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a subquery.  This is perhaps simplest as two separate updates:

```
update t
    set credit = (select sum(t2.amount)
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.id in (10001, 10002, 10003)
    where id = 10004;

update t
    set credit = (select sum(t2.amount)
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.id in (30001, 30002)
    where id = 30003;
```

You could combine these into a single statement, but I don't think it is worth it.

Comment: I've tried this in VBA: `SQL1 = "UPDATE test SET CREDIT = (SELECT SUM(T.CREDIT) FROM test AS T WHERE T.ID IN ('10001','10002','10003')) WHERE ID LIKE '10004';"`
   and  `DoCmd.RunSQL SQL1` but it showed error '3073': the operation must use an updatable query